# How to ignore formatting a part of the code in Delphi IDE code formatter?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I've found a question from 12 years ago, when there wasn't a way to ignore a part of code in Embarcadero Delphi's code formatter. Has something changed since then, and there is some way to do this now?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: "I've found a question from 12 years ago" needs a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of this writing, there is no way to tell the code formatter to ignore a portion of code.  The formatter applies to the entire file, unless you have selected a piece of code then it formats just that code instead.

Comment: If you have a chunk of code selected, the formatter will work with just that instead of the entire file.

Answer (score 2):

The code formatter coming with the [GExperts](https://blog.dummzeuch.de/experimental-gexperts-version/) plugin for Delphi can exclude code parts from formatting using special directives in code. Per default `{(*}` for start and `{*)}` for end an block are used where no formatting shall take place.

These directives are also fully customizable in the options dialog for the code formatter:
[image: GExperts code formatter misc. options]

Comment: It can also only format the selected lines.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the current version.

You can format just a selected block, but a way to automatically exclude a block of code would be great.